# C#: custom control vs native control

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, custom-controls

ALL,
I am trying to develop a C# Windows Forms application.
For that I needed to make a custom control that is derived from the GroupBox.

Now for the problem.
I have a form and on the form I put a grid box. On 1 cell I put a GroupBox and on another cell I put my custom control.
For both controls properties I put "ColumnSpan" to be 3 as grid has 3 columns.
The native control display itself properly, meaning it is stretched.
The custom control display itself incorrectly, meaning it is not stretched.

I checked and all properties in the properties inspector are the same.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Try placing your control on the highest container on the tree (the Form itself) and dock it. Will it size as expected?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, it's TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: @Aphelion, dock it how? And what do you mean by size as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason custom controls do not resize themselves. So all I had to do in the GUI designer is to resize the control.

Thank you for reading and hopefully it will help someone else.